# Magento 2 Notice: Undefined variable: images

Tags: magento2, variables

I use custom variable in Mirasvit Extension for export parent images also from variants.

For test I export single product and working correct. Now I set filter with export all configurable products in website and I get issue:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: images in /home/azinvest/domains/under.pl/public_html/pub/media/feed/tmp/16110634559723.php on line 14
```

On line 14 custom variable  is:

```
 }
    $images = implode(', ', $images);
}
```

Here is full code dynamic variable.

```
$storeManager = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$mediaUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
if ($product->getTypeId() != 'configurable') {
$images = $mediaUrl . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
} else {
    $children = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
    foreach ($children as $child){
        if ($child->getMediaGalleryImages()) {
            foreach ($child->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
    $images[] = $mediaUrl . 'catalog/product' . $image['file'];
            }
        }
}
    $images = implode(', ', $images);
}
return  $images;
```

Any solution?

Comment: Define the $images variable blank above the if condition like this , $images = ' ';

Answer (score 0):

please define variable images before if the condition

Ex. $images = ' ';

Comment: Can you explain this further? Can you improve our code? Thanks!

Comment: yes, please share full code